# lambda -> delegate doesn't compile

Tags: c#, .net, delegates, lambda, action

The last statement does not compile. please refer to the comments along with the code for the detail of my question.

```
class Test
{
    private static void Foo(Delegate d){}

    private static void Bar(Action a){}

    static void Main()
    {
        Foo(new Action(() => { Console.WriteLine("a"); })); // Action converts to Delegate implicitly

        Bar(() => { Console.WriteLine("b"); }); // lambda converts to Action implicitly

        Foo(() => { Console.WriteLine("c"); }); // Why doesn't this compile ? (lambda converts to Action implicitly, and then Action converts to Delegate implicitly)
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider including the compiler error messages in the post. It will aid in search-ability as well as context (for people who have not run into this situation before) -- and consider making the title *relevant* to the question :) [A humanized form of the error message should be a good starting point for the title]

Comment: still have another question: we already have lambda and Action, Func<T>, why do we still need delegate? If there is NO such thing called delegate, there will be NO such annoying problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the .net compiler doesn't know what type of delegate to turn the lambda into.  It could be an Action, or it could be a `void MyDelegate()`.

If you change it as follows, it should work:

```
Foo(new Action(() => { Console.WriteLine("c"); }));
```

Comment: or create  `private delegate void FooDelegate();` and use it.

Answer (score 1):

Why should the compiler know how to two-step: from lambda -> Action -> Delegate?

This compiles:

```
class Test
{
    private static void Foo(Delegate d) { }

    private static void Bar(Action a) { }

    static void Main()
    {
        Foo(new Action(() => { Console.WriteLine("world2"); })); // Action converts to Delegate implicitly

        Bar(() => { Console.WriteLine("world3"); }); // lambda converts to Action implicitly

        Foo((Action)(() => { Console.WriteLine("world3"); })); // This compiles
    }
}
```